# How to make a ladder for hermit crabs?

Tags: hermit-crabs

I'd like to know how to make a ladder easy for my hermit crabs to climb to get to their hammock. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SE! :) As a Q&A site we function a little differently from a regular forum; each question needs its own starting post, so I've removed your second question. Feel free to check whether it's been answered before, and ask it separately from this one if it hasn't.